# magento - unable to save products in quote

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, quote

I am working magento payment gateway

```
$product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
$product_id = $product_model->getIdBySku('billmate_faktura_'.$code);
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

$price = $_product->getPrice();
$orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setProduct($_product)
    ->setQuoteItemId(0)
    ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
    ->setProductId($product_id)
    ->setProductType($_product->getTypeId())
    ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
    ->setTotalQtyOrdered(1)
    ->setQtyOrdered(1)
    ->setQty(1)
    ->setName($_product->getName())
    ->setSku($_product->getSku())
    ->setPrice($price)
    ->setBasePrice($price)
    ->setOriginalPrice($price)
    ->setRowTotal($price)
    ->setBaseRowTotal($price);
    $quote->addItem($orderItem);

    $quote->save();
```

When i complete order. i can't see this product in admin order detail page. please tell me if i did something wrong.

This is not working actually i am try to add this product for invoice fee purpose but when i complete order then my fee product not added anywhere.

Comment: Fee's should not be products. It should be, you know - a fee. You can add a custom payment fee collector for when `$quote->collectTotals()` runs.

Answer (score 2):

<del>You still need to define a payment method, and service the order.</del>

EDIT: As per comment:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->setWebsiteId(1) // your website ID
    ->loadByEmail($email); //valid customer email address
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);
$product_info = array('qty'=>1);
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($product_info));
$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method'=>$payment)); //your payment method
$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->reserveOrderId();
$quote->setIsActive(0);
$quote->save();
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
$order = $service->getOrder();
$order->save();
```

Comment: There's a comprehensive guide on programatically creating orders overe here: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/

Comment: this is not working actually i am try to add this product for invoice fee purpose but when i complete order then my fee product not added anywhere

Comment: Did you have a look at the guide on inchoo.net?

Comment: yes read this tutorial but not works for me

Comment: I've updated the answer, give that a shot and let me know if you're still having issues. This works for me. Otherwise check system.log for an error message.

Comment: throwing error Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in /var/www-magento/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php on line 808